# How to use regex's "findall()" function to populate a dictionary when it's possible for there to be no matches in the string?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to use regex to populate the values of a dictionary in python. I'm using regex because the original format of the strings I'm pulling the data from is not consistent from string to string, but the relevant data within the string is easy to find and consistently formatted.

Some of the strings contain no matches for a given key, so the `findall` function of regex would return an empty list. Therefore, the following code, where I use `findall` and simply address the 0th element to populate the dictionary, will only work when the string contains a match for every key, throwing an `IndexError` otherwise.

```py
import re

def main():
    my_string = "JC is a 45 year-old male."
    info = {
        "Name": re.findall(r"[A-Z][A-Z]", my_string)[0],
        "Age": re.findall(r"\d{1,2}", my_string)[0],
        "Sex": re.findall(r" male| female", my_string)[0].lstrip()
    }

main()
```

This code, expectedly, gives the dictionary

```
{
    "Name": "JC",
    "Age": '45',
    "Sex": "male"
}
```

The code I have that actually works correctly looks like this:

```py
import re

def main():
    my_string = "JC is a 45 year-old."
    info = {
        "Name": '',
        "Age": '',
        "Sex": ''
    }
    if re.findall(r"[A-Z][A-Z]", my_string):
        info["Name"] = re.findall(r"[A-Z][A-Z]", my_string)[0]
    if re.findall(r"\d{1,2}", my_string):
        info["Age"] = re.findall(r"\d{1,2}", my_string)[0]
    if re.findall(r" male| female", my_string):
        info["Sex"] = re.findall(r" male| female", my_string)[0].lstrip()


main()
```

And gives the dictionary

```
{
    "Name": "JC",
    "Age": "45",
    "Sex": ''
}
```

I'd like to do this in a more concise way. The actual dictionary for what I'm doing contains many more keys than just those 3, and I feel like there has to be a better way than having an `if` statement for every key. Thanks!

Comment: If you only want the first match, why don't you use `re.search` instead of `re.findall`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the keys and their respective regexes as key value pairs in another dictionary:

```
key_regexes = {
    "Name": r"[A-Z][A-Z]",
    "Age": r"\d{1,2}",
    "Sex": r"\bmale\b|\bfemale\b"
}
```

And then, loop through the keys of the dictionary, get the regexes, and match each one against the input string. In each iteration, you'll be adding a new key to the result dictionary:

```
result = {}
for key in key_regexes:
    regex = key_regexes[key]
    match = re.search(regex, my_string)
    if match:
        result[key] = match.group(0)
    else:
        result[key] = ''
```

Note that you will not be able to use the `lstrip`, which is why I changed the regex to `r"\bmale\b|\bfemale\b"`.